# C Makefile Linking Error: Undefined reference to 'main'

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I have tried looking through other answers, unfortunately I have not found anyone with quite the same problem. I am trying to link two C files together, one has a header file, and the other the main file. When trying to make I receive this error:

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is the makefile I use to compile.

```
INC_DIR = include
SRC_DIR = src
BIN_DIR = bin
UNAME := $(shell uname)
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c11 -g -I$(INC_DIR) -I/usr/include/libxml2/
LDFLAGS= -L.

all: XMLParser

XMLParser: $(BIN_DIR)/XMLParser.o $(BIN_DIR)/SVGParser.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o XMLParser $(BIN_DIR)/XMLParser.o $(BIN_DIR)/SVGParser.o

$(BIN_DIR)/XMLParser.o: $(SRC_DIR)/XMLParser.c $(INC_DIR)/SVGParser.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/XMLParser.o -c $(SRC_DIR)/XMLParser.c

$(BIN_DIR)/SVGParser.o: $(SRC_DIR)/SVGParser.c $(INC_DIR)/SVGParser.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -o $(BIN_DIR)/SVGParser.o $(SRC_DIR)/SVGParser.c

clean:
    rm *.o XMLParser $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

XMLParser.c has my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ...;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It's not necessary to add *I've accepted the answer below* to your post. We can see that you've accepted it, because it has a  green checkmark next to it that means it's been accepted.

Comment: When asking for help please don't forget to include the compile line that was run that generated the error message, not just the error message itself.  If you'd included the compile command, so that we saw that it was the `SVGParser.o` command that generated the error, it would have been much faster/simpler to determine the problem without having to painstakingly examine the entire makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recipe for generating the intermediate `SVGParser.o` is attempting to link and generate a runnable executable. You need to add `-c` to skip the link step.

You will also need to remove the `—libs` on that object file and move it to the final link step. In other words add `xml2-config —libs` for the rule generating the final `XMLParser`  target.

Disclaimer: I’ve never specifically used `xml2-config`, so I guess there’s some chance I’m wrong here, but it’s a very common paradigm for building and linking against complex libraries, I assume it’s following the same patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A full sample code showing the error must be posted to be able to test it elsewhere, so I cannot fully test your makefile, but providing a true `main()` and see what happens.

After generating stub files to check your `Makefile` I found the following output from `make`:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -std=c11 -g -Iinclude -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -o bin/XMLParser.o -c src/XMLParser.c
gcc -Wall -std=c11 -g -Iinclude -I/usr/include/libxml2/ `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -o bin/SVGParser.o src/SVGParser.c
/usr/local/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-freebsd13.0/10.2.1/../../../crt1.o: en la función `_start':
/home/usr/src/lib/csu/amd64/crt1_c.c:75: referencia a `main' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /home/lcu/so/makefile
$ _
```

which is trying to link (alone) the module `SVGParser.o` (THIS IS BECAUSE YOU DIDN'T ADD THE `-c` COMPILATION OPTION TO COMPILE ONLY).

Change the compilation line for the `SVGParser.o` module to use the `-c` compile-only option and you will get the executable properly.